# x86 vs x86_64 calling convention

Tags: c, assembly, calling-convention

We've got two architectures and two different years: x86 in 2007 and x86_64 in 2017. In a book published in 2007 basing on x86, there's an example listed for a compiled file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void usage(char *program_name) {

    printf("Usage: %s <message> <# of times to repeat>\n", program_name);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i, count;

    if(argc < 3)            // If fewer than 3 arguments are used, 
        usage(argv[0]);     // display usage message and exit.

    count = atoi(argv[2]);  // Convert the 2nd arg into an integer.
    printf("Repeating %d times..\n", count);

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%3d - %s\n", i, argv[1]);   // Printf the 1st arg.

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling via *gcc -g -o file.o file.c* and disassembling the file in gdb or simply objdumping the file on *x86_64*: it looks like this:

```
0000000000000000 <usage>:
 0: 55                      push   rbp
 1: 48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
 4: 48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
 8: 48 89 7d f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rdi
 c: 48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
10: 48 89 c6                mov    rsi,rax
13: 48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0x0]  # 1a <usage+0x1a>
1a: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
1f: e8 00 00 00 00          call   24 <usage+0x24>
24: bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
29: e8 00 00 00 00          call   2e <main>

000000000000002e <main>:
2e: 55                      push   rbp
2f: 48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
32: 48 83 ec 20             sub    rsp,0x20
36: 89 7d ec                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
39: 48 89 75 e0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rsi
3d: 83 7d ec 02             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],0x2
41: 7f 0f                   jg     52 <main+0x24>
43: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
47: 48 8b 00                mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
4a: 48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
4d: e8 00 00 00 00          call   52 <main+0x24>
52: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
56: 48 83 c0 10             add    rax,0x10
5a: 48 8b 00                mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
5d: 48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
60: e8 00 00 00 00          call   65 <main+0x37>
65: 89 45 f8                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],eax
68: 8b 45 f8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
6b: 89 c6                   mov    esi,eax
6d: 48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0x0]  # 74 <main+0x46>
74: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
79: e8 00 00 00 00          call   7e <main+0x50>
7e: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
85: eb 25                   jmp    ac <main+0x7e>
87: 48 8b 45 e0             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
8b: 48 83 c0 08             add    rax,0x8
8f: 48 8b 10                mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rax]
92: 8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
95: 89 c6                   mov    esi,eax
97: 48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0x0]  # 9e <main+0x70>
9e: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
a3: e8 00 00 00 00          call   a8 <main+0x7a>
a8: 83 45 fc 01             add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
ac: 8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
af: 3b 45 f8                cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
b2: 7c d3                   jl     87 <main+0x59>
b4: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
b9: c9                      leave  
ba: c3                      ret
```

However, from what I've learned in assembler on *x86* is that before calling a function, the usual calling convention (pushing rbp, moving rsp to rbp, basically building a new stack frame plus all arguments) sets in. But in the above objdump output of main, there is no line like

```
call    <addr_of_function_usage>    # <usage+0x0>
```

like in x86 generally or in the book. So my question is, where in this objdump does the call to the usage function take place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think there has to be a call at all? Please provide a reference to the ABI of your platform or the C standard.

Comment: You're looking at the disassembly of the object file, which will make no sense to you (or me for that matter). Consider adding `-masm=intel -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm` and changing `-c` to `-S` when compiling and look at `file.s`. You'll find the code to be more understandable.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune you're right, honestly didn't know abot this. But what exactly did you mean with "dissasembly of the object file, which will make no sense"? shouldn't the objdump and its assembly output be the same?

Comment: Chrono means that those `e8 00 00 00 00` will be replaced with correct offsets by the linker. As standing they are misleading. The `call   52 <main+0x24>` is your call. Also, note that this is not related to the ABI and that x86_64 ABI is very different from the x86 one.

Comment: @MargaretBloom thanks for the clarification. this closes my case now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an object file, the addresses of functions aren't filled in yet. For this reason, the disassembler has trouble seeing what functions you try to call. If you look at the disassembly, you see a bunch of `call` instructions, one of these probably calls `usage`. It seems to be the `call` at address `0x42`.